# How to delete subkey, value pair in a python Ordered Dictionary based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python dictionary with an ordered dictionary inside each key, there is over 10 million, key, subkey, value pairs. I want to delete subkeys and their values based on numeric conditions and was wondering how to do that in an efficient way.

```
#My input dictionary 

dict = {'Math': OrderedDict([('John', 0.0),
              ('Peter', 22.2222),
              ('Alex', 60.212),
              ('Ben', 82.19)]),
 'Physics': OrderedDict([('John', 92.25),
              ('Peter', 35.22),
              ('Alex', 18.22),
              ('Ben', 76.19)]),
 'Chemistry': OrderedDict([('John', 19),
              ('Peter', 24),
              ('Alex', 6),
              ('Ben', 100)])
 }

#I want my output to delete subkey pairs where value is less than 20, for eg.
out_dict = {'Math': OrderedDict([('Peter', 22.2222),              
              ('Alex', 60.212),
              ('Ben', 82.19)]),
 'Physics': OrderedDict([('John', 92.25),
              ('Peter', 35.22),
              ('Ben', 76.19)]),
 'Chemistry': OrderedDict([('Peter', 24),
              ('Ben', 100)])
 }
```

I have tried:

```
for key in [key for key in dict if key>=20]: 
    del dict[key]
```

I was getting a TypeError.

Comment: Why this is tagged pandas? This can be easily solved with for loops ..., so what is your specific problem?

Comment: I have a dictionary with over 10 million key value pair combinations, i wanted to solve this efficiency as i want sure if looping can solve it efficiently.

Comment: Well you should put that in your question. Also, did you try looping over it?

Comment: Edited the question to reflect my data size. I did try looping and was getting a 'TypeError : '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: So you only want the pairs, or you want to maintain the same structure?

Comment: Maintaining the same structure would be ideal.

Comment: I added a pandas solution to complement RaySteams excellent solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import pprint
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'Math': OrderedDict([('John', 0.0), ('Peter', 22.2222), ('Alex', 60.212), ('Ben', 82.19)]),
     'Physics': OrderedDict([('John', 92.25), ('Peter', 35.22), ('Alex', 18.22), ('Ben', 76.19)]),
     'Chemistry': OrderedDict([('John', 19), ('Peter', 24), ('Alex', 6), ('Ben', 100)])
     }

threshold = 20
for key, grades in d.items():
    d[key] = OrderedDict((name, grade) for name, grade in grades.items() if grade > 20)

pprint.pprint(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'Chemistry': OrderedDict([('Peter', 24), ('Ben', 100)]),
 'Math': OrderedDict([('Peter', 22.2222), ('Alex', 60.212), ('Ben', 82.19)]),
 'Physics': OrderedDict([('John', 92.25), ('Peter', 35.22), ('Ben', 76.19)])}
```

Now the problem with your attempt is that you are comparing strings to integers:

```
[key for key in dict if key>=20]
```

Here the keys in dict are string objects, as a side note do not use `dict` as a variable name as it shadows the built-in [name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: This works great, thanks @RaySteam. Just wondering how to delete empty ordered dictionary incase all the values are above threshold?

Comment: @user12229564 perhaps ask that as a new question, or play around with it yourself.  One way to do it is `if not d[key]:  del d[key]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for pandas, as that's in the tag list:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'Math': OrderedDict([('John', 0.0), ('Peter', 22.2222), ('Alex', 60.212), ('Ben', 82.19)]),
     'Physics': OrderedDict([('John', 92.25), ('Peter', 35.22), ('Alex', 18.22), ('Ben', 76.19)]),
     'Chemistry': OrderedDict([('John', 19), ('Peter', 24), ('Alex', 6), ('Ben', 100)])
     }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)
thedict = {} 
for x,y in df2.unstack()[df2.unstack()>20].items(): 
  thedict[x[0]] = [] 
for x,y in df2.unstack()[df2.unstack()>20].items(): 
  thedict[x[0]].append((x[1],y)) 
for k,y in thedict.items(): 
  thedict[k] = OrderedDict(y)
```

output:

```
thedict                                                                                                                                                                                          

{'Math': OrderedDict([('Peter', 22.2222), ('Alex', 60.212), ('Ben', 82.19)]),
 'Physics': OrderedDict([('John', 92.25), ('Peter', 35.22), ('Ben', 76.19)]),
 'Chemistry': OrderedDict([('Peter', 24.0), ('Ben', 100.0)])}
```